# How do I respond to touching an empty UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like to launch my "add item" form in response to touching an empty cell (the next blank cell), sort of like the stock "Reminders" app. didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work for this and I don't have a clue what does.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a button to the tableFooterView

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this just yet. What is the tableFooterView? The documentation says "Returns an accessory view that is displayed below the table." Is that referring to the area beneath the cells? If so, is it the whole area or just the next open cell?

Comment: it is bottom part of table (footer)
just make new button and table.tableFooterView = yourButton;
or in XCode Interface Builder drag new button to bottom part of table view

Answer (score 1):

You could add a tap gesture recognizer to the table view, but be sure to test if the user tapped a table view cell or not.

Comment: If the user adds enough items the tableView will be full of cells. Wouldn't you always tap on one?

Comment: I had slightly different needs (dismissing a picker view overlaying the tableview when an empty cell is touched) and this worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna the last cell of your table view to be an add button so that you can add a cell directly without putting the table view in edit mode, then here is what you can do:

1. For the array you use to populate the table view, always make sure the last cell is a dummy object you use to add a row only.
2. in your  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, make sure check whether indexPath.row is equal to [array count], if that's the same, then
3. insert whatever the object you create to your array at index = [array count]-1.
4. Call your [tableview reload] method. Then you will see the cell append to the table view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this idea. What I'm trying to emulate is the "Reminders" app. In that app the last cell is blank but it does not appear to be the footer. It still has a box around it but it is blank. Do you think this is the method they used for that? It makes sense in my mind.

Comment: I looked at some screenshots and it's hard to convey. I don't think it's that important. I like this idea anyway. I'm wondering how to implement this when my data is in CoreData and I'm pulling it with a FetchedResultsController?

Comment: Sorry I only use sqlite since i need it for other platforms. But i don't think how to pull data matters. You only need to pull data once when you initialize your NSMutableArray, and you write it back whenever the save got called. Or maybe I am wrong and core data operate totally differently? Sorry i just don't know anything about core data.